# specify group by field in django 1.2

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to use `annotate` to count the number of occurances in my model, however it is not using the right field in the group by statment.  instead of using the field i want (i.e. the one specified in the count function) it uses the primary key of the model. e.g.

```
ObjectHistory.objects.annotate(revisions=Count('resource'))
```

produces sql

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`resources_objecthistory`.`resource_id`) AS `revisions` FROM `resources_objecthistory` GROUP BY `resources_objecthistory`.`history_id`
```

where `history_id` is the primary key of ObjectHistory

what I want is:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`resources_objecthistory`.`resource_id`) AS `revisions` FROM `resources_objecthistory` GROUP BY `resources_objecthistory`.`resource_id
```

I found that by putting

```
ObjectHistory.objects.values.('resource').annotate(revisions=Count('resource'))
```

it put the right group by field but then i didn't have access to the other fields in the model.

How do I specify to use resource_id in the group by field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the raw method as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/)

e.g.

> ObjectHistory.objects.raw("SELECT *,
>   COUNT(`resources_objecthistory`.`resource_id`)
>   AS `revisions` FROM
>   `resources_objecthistory` GROUP BY
>   `resources_objecthistory`.`resource_id")

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    ObjectHistory.objects.values.('resource').\
    extra(select_params=('attribute1', 'attribute2'))\
    .annotate(revisions=Count('resource'))
```